# Improper integral quotient in a limit statement

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

This seemingly straightforward problem has been giving me a lot of trouble.

For $f$ and $g$, which are positive and continuous functions on $[1,\infty)$, show that if $$L = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$ is a real number, then $$L = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\int_x^\infty f}{\int_x^\infty g}$$

The intuition is rather clear, but the position of $x$ in the second limit statement is throwing me off. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is true if one of the two integrals is convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $\epsilon\gt0$, there is an $N$ so that for $x\ge N$, we have
$$
(L-\epsilon)g(x)\le f(x)\le g(x)(L+\epsilon)\tag{1}
$$
Thus, for $x\ge N$, we have
$$
(L-\epsilon)\int_x^\infty g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\le\int_x^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\le(L+\epsilon)\int_x^\infty g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}
$$
Therefore, assuming the integrals converge,
$$
L-\epsilon\le\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_x^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}{\int_x^\infty g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}\le L+\epsilon\tag{3}
$$
Since $(3)$ is true for any $\epsilon\gt0$, we have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_x^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}{\int_x^\infty g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}=L\tag{4}
$$

Comment: Thank you much for your very elegant response. The problem as written, did not specify that the integrals necessarily converge. Is the statement untrue if that is not the case?

Comment: @sequenceDerivative: If the integrals do not converge (at least one of them), you risk getting $\frac \infty \infty$ and you know how bad this is. There is a theorem, though, which tells you that if $L \in (0, \infty)$, then those two integrals either diverge, or converge (i.e. they have both the same behaviour).

Comment: Thank you Alex. I am aware of the theorem which states that if one converges, then the other must. In the case they do diverge, is it at all possible for their quotient to be a real number? such as would be implied here. Or is it likely that this was a poorly worded problem and one of the hypotheses should have been "and both integrals converge"?

Comment: @sequenceDerivative: if either integral diverges, then both diverge and then you cannot evaluate $\frac{\int_x^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}{\int_x^\infty g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}$ for any $x$.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I don't know what I was thinking. Thanks much

Comment: @robjohn: No, why would you say that? If $f = \Bbb e^{-x}$ and $g=1$, then $\lim \frac f g = 0$, $\int g$ diverges but $\int f$ doesn't. Both your proof and mine miss cases like this.

Comment: @AlexM.: sorry, I thought $L\gt0$. What I said is not true if $L=0$.

Comment: @AlexM.: If $L=0$, then I believe my answer works, does it not?

Comment: @robjohn: There are two cases to consider: $L = 0$ and both integrals convergent; $L = 0$ and one of them divergent (which again has two subcases: $\int f$ divergent and, respectively, $\int g$ divergent). I'm sure that the problem is easy, it is just annoying to consider all these cases.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an excellent example where L'Hospital's theorem might help. Intuitively, $\lim \limits _{x \to \infty} \int \limits _x ^\infty f(t) \ \Bbb d t = \infty$, but we need to make this rigorous. The problem is that, if you want to differentiate this integral with respect to $x$, what do you do to $\infty'$? This doesn't make any sense. Therefore, write

$$\int \limits _x ^\infty f(t) \ \Bbb d t = \int \limits _x ^1 f(t) \ \Bbb d t + \int \limits _1 ^\infty f(t) \ \Bbb d t$$

and notice that

$$\frac {\Bbb d} {\Bbb d x} \int \limits _x ^\infty f(t) \ \Bbb d t = \frac {\Bbb d} {\Bbb d x} \int \limits _x ^1 f(t) \ \Bbb d t + 0 = - f(x) ,$$

which means that the application of l'Hospital's theorem gives us

$$\lim \limits _{x \to \infty} \frac {\int \limits _x ^\infty f(t) \ \Bbb d t} {\int \limits _x ^\infty g(t) \ \Bbb d t} = \lim \limits _{x \to \infty} \frac {-f(x)} {-g(x)} = L .$$

---

Let's address the issue of the convergence of these integrals. First, if $L>0$ then the two integrals converge (otherwise the fraction $\frac {\int _x ^\infty f} {\int _x ^\infty g}$ wouldn't make sense).

If $L = 0$, then there exist an $x_0 > 1$ such that $f(x) \le g(x)$ for $x \ge x_0$. This rules out the possibility that $\int _x ^\infty f$ diverges, because in this case we would also have $\int _x ^\infty g$ divergent and this situation has been ruled out. There remains the possibility of having $\int _x ^\infty f$ convergent and $\int _x ^\infty g$ divergent, but this case gives us immediately that

$$\frac {\int \limits _x ^\infty f(t) \ \Bbb d t} {\int \limits _x ^\infty g(t) \ \Bbb d t} = \frac {\text {finite}} \infty = 0 ,$$

whence it follows that the limit of the fraction with integrals is $0$ too, therefore equal to $L$ as required.

The case $L = \infty$ is ruled out by the requirement that $L$ be a real number, which $\infty$ is not.